# For which values of $ x$ we have $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{\tan(n!)-n!}$ converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits-and-convergence, trigonometric-sums

The copy of this question is posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3700402/156150)

I have tried to to determine values of real $x$ for which $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{\tan(n!)-n!}$ converges but I can't , Presumably the set of values  $\{ n! \bmod 2\pi\mathbb Z\}$ is dense in $[0,2\pi]$  then $\tan(n!)$ will be large arbitrarily infinitely often, and the difference $\tan(n!)-n!$ would be probably small. However I don't know anything about limit of the fraction $\frac{\tan(n!)}{n!}$ for large $n$, And I have used Stiriling formula but it weren't helpful, This really forbide me to determine how $x$ values should be to get the titled series converge, then my question is :

> **Question:**
> For which values of real number  $x$ we have $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{\tan(n!)-n!}$ converges ? We may avoid trivial case $x=0$ , In particular how we  prove the set of values  $\{ n! \bmod 2\pi\mathbb Z\}$ is dense in $[0,2\pi]$ ?

**Note**:I have used this trick for approximation : $n! = e(-1)^{n+1}/(n+1) + O(1/n^2) (\mod \mathbb Z)$ implies that $\tan(\pi n!)-n!=\pi e((-1)^{n+1}/(n+1) + O(1/n^2)) -\frac{1}{\pi})(\mod \mathbb Z)$ but this what could saying to  me ? Probably conditional convergence could be happen here .

**Addedendum**

I'm interested to evaluate the above series because this need to prove $\{ n! \bmod 2\pi\mathbb Z\}$ is dense in $[0,2\pi]$  which is related to irrationality measure and Bounds approximation  of $\pi$ which it is interesting in number theory and in the same time looking to the behavior of $\tan(n!)-n!$ for large $n$ which it help to get bounds for some arithmitic functions , Also to loook to the relationship of convergence of series to  lacunar Fourier series which we have a lot of results on convergence for them

using mathematica code  for $n=400$,  $\tan(n!)-n!$ I have got the below plot and this is the code ,

```
Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 800},
  lst = Table[Tan[n!] - n!, {n, 0, 400}];
  ListPlot[N[Accumulate[lst], 200], PlotRange -> All]
  ]
```

[image]

Comment: Does this question fit into a larger picture? Why is this question important to you?

Comment: @BenMcKay, Sorry I missed to add motivation of that question, I'm already adding that in Addedendum

Comment: However , I don't know why downvote however that question is in the level of research and in the same time I have showed its motivation

Comment: Your question is intersting whene i plot the function $f(t)=\tan(t)-t$, we can see that almost values of $f(n)$ with $n$ positive integers are negative and diverge fast.

Comment: @Lagrida , probably you missed factorial in t , and in the same time the power of x is the approximation of n! by (2k+1) pi/2

Comment: 12 versions in 12 hours.